# Webhook - username and password to the header to verify message authenticity

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am trying to validate webhook validation using username and password, but in header values are not coming. Any idea how to fetch/ read them from request header? Is dere any different key name?
I tried all these but always empty

```
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders headers = Request.Headers;
        string username = string.Empty;
        string pwd = string.Empty;

        string username1 = string.Empty;
        string pwd1 = string.Empty;


        if (headers.Contains("X-DocuSign-UserName"))
        {
            username1 = headers.GetValues("X-DocuSign-Password").First();
        }
        if (headers.Contains("X-DocuSign-Password"))
        {
            pwd1 = headers.GetValues("X-DocuSign-Password").First();
        }

        if (headers.Contains("username"))
        {
            username = headers.GetValues("username").First();
        }
        if (headers.Contains("password"))
        {
            pwd = headers.GetValues("password").First();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!! Please check/accept the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I use the DocuSign webhook **Basic Auth** feature, how can my listener (my server) see the incoming name/password?

**Answer:** `Basic Auth` is a standard. It is sent via the `Authorization` header. The format is described in [RFC 7617](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617) and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

You'd use `headers.GetValues("Authorization")`

Note that Basic Auth is often implemented by your web server, rather than by the application.

Also: webhooks require that your listener have an address on the public Internet. That often requires opening a hole in your firewall.

An alternative is available if you don't want to make a hole in your firewall: queue the notification messages on a PAAS service (eg AWS, Azure, etc). Then your app, from behind the firewall, can use long polling to quickly receive the notifications. Result: no firewall holes needed! [Docs and example code for this technique.](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4)